# How to always show div when I scroll a JSF page

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2

I have a div layer into JSF page:

```
<p:outputPanel id="outputComponent">
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: black; left: 350px; top: 0px; width: 700px; padding: 10px; border-radius: 6px;">

        <div class="container">
            Component Profile
        </div>
        <br/>
        <!-- <h:outputText value="#{TreeViewController.initComponent()}" /> -->

        <table>
            <col width="280"/><col width="130"/>

            <ui:repeat var="ud" value="#{TreeViewController.componentData}">

                <tr>
                    <td>Component ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.componentStatsID}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.componentName}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </ui:repeat>
        </table>

    </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```

I'm interested how I can show always this div on the center of the display even when I scroll the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) property value `fixed`. I wasn't sure if you wanted it to be centered both vertically and horizontally, but this solution works for both. Change the width to whatever you like and the `top: 50%` depending on the height of your div.

**CSS**

```
.static {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Apply the static class on your div and remove: `style="position: absolute; background-color: black; left: 350px; top: 0px; width: 700px; padding: 10px; border-radius: 6px;"`

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HwHUS/1/